# how much time does it take to backup 100gb database with RMAN and expdp?

Tags: database-backups, rman

how much time does it take to backup 100 GB database with RMAN and expdp?

I want to take backup of the system before applying the partitioning activity. In case of error, backup data restore immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the system, I would say RMAN would take something between 1 to 2 hours. 
EXPDP would probably take more than RMAN.

Comment: RMAN captures the index??

Comment: as far as I know, it does.

Comment: Now I want to do table backup..Is it possible?